# How do I retrieve the post variables from $http.post/angular on my node backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post, parameters

Here is my front end.

```
auth
var time = 5;

$http.post('/tasks/addTime', null, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.getToken()
    },
    data: {
        id: "Me",
        time: time,
    }
});
```

Here is the back

```
router.post('/tasks/addTime', auth, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
});
```

I am able to see the data structure req is echoed so I am calling the backend properly.. how do I get access to my "id" and "time" variables?

Comment: are they not in the `req` object?

Comment: I tried echoing req.. there was a lot of stuff. Specifically I tried req.body and it was empty. Just imagining this has to have been done successfully numerous times but its a sort of difficult thing to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node processes POST data in chunks.  Your function needs to receive the chunks of data and build a complete body.  There are frameworks such as Express which will handle this for you, but the following is an example of how to do this yourself:

```
router.post('/tasks/addTime', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var body = "";
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function () {
    console.log('POSTed: ' + body);
  });
});
```

It is important to note, when listening for POST data, that the `req` object is also an [Event Emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter). `req`, therefore, will emit a `'data'` event whenever a `chunk` of incoming data is received; when there is no more incoming data, the `'end'` event is emitted. So, in our case, we listen for `'data'` events. Once all the data is recieved, we log the data to the console.

Using Express, you should also have an extra object, [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

> **`req.params`**
>
> An object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route `/user/:name`, then the “name” property is available as `req.params.name`. This object defaults to `{}`.

You can also use [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) with the help of an Express middleware:

> **`req.body`**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is `undefined`, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Comment: Thanks for the response. My friend said that this code gave him issues, so I will take a look tonight and attempt to get this to work and see if he missed anything. I'll be giving you the correct answer if I can get our setup to work with this approach.

Comment: Could you give us an example of an express framework that will do this sort of thing if you have time? We are using express so it may be prudent to check it out anyways.